# On PageLoad show Magento Static block in ajax

Tags: ajax, magento

I am running on Magento 1.7 and its a fresh copy.

What I want to achieve: 
On pageload of the website, display the newsletter template block

`{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}`

as a pop-up window in Magento once, where the cookies will expire after a given period of time eg: 1 week.

The answers on web are either not specific, or not detailed enough as my knowledge is not broad on scripts.

What I tried so far:

#### attempt to add a lightbox:

1) Add Lightbox CSS  & JS

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('lightbox/lightbox.js'); ?>"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('lightbox/lightbox.css'); ?>" media="screen"/>
```

2) In view.phtml I added a link

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('measurement')->toHtml() ?>" rel="lightbox">Size chart</a>
```

The lightbox is working but the static block is not called... still figuring out how to call a static box..

Comment: Could you post the code you have tried so far so we can see how far you have got.

Comment: Hi I have edited the code, I managed to do just only a basic pop up window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully called a popup consisting static block using the steps below.

http://jsfiddle.net/5USUu/

So basically we need to:

1. Add .js and .css files - I'm using colorbox
2. Define the function
3. Call the function

1) Add the following script in header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getJSUrl('pop/colorbox.css'); ?>" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getJSUrl('pop/popup.css'); ?>" />
<script language="javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJSUrl('pop/colorbox.js'); ?>"></script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
 if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1){
      var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15; 
      var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
      document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString(); 
      jQuery.colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
      }
      jQuery(".open_popup").colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
      });
</script>
```

2) Add this link in html that link to your pop up

```
<a href="#" class="open_popup">Click here to open the popup</a>
```

3) Add the html that contains your static block identifier

```
<div style='display:none'>
<div id='subscribe_popup' style='padding:10px;'> 
<!-- BEGIN #subs-container --> 
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('subscribe')->toHtml() ?>
<div id="subs-container" class="clearfix"> </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END subscribe popup-->
```

Comment: Good job on figuring out a solution to your own problem, but what's AJAX about this solution? Seems to me you're rendering content in hidden view and then display it on demand.